# Powershell extract TCP port from log file to update Firewall rule

Tags: powershell, firewall

Every time our FlexLm server reboots, the licensing services reset their input TCP port. I want to extract the new TCP port from the log file to update the firewall rule. I can extract the port number, but the script does not like the single quote delimiter.

```
$IdeateLog = "C:\Autodesk\Network License Manager\ideate.log"
$LogTxt= "*(lmgrd) ideate using TCP-port*"

$content = Get-Content $IdeateLog
$content | foreach {
        if ($_ -ilike $LogTxt){
        $IdeatePortTxt = $_ -replace "ideate using TCP-port ",""
        $IdeatePortTxtLen = $IdeatePortTxt.Length - 17
        $IdeatePortNo = "'"+ $IdeatePortTxt.Substring(17, $IdeatePortTxtLen) + "'"
        }
      }
$tempPort = '65443'

get-netfirewallrule -DisplayName "*LMtools - Ideate*" | where {$_.Direction -eq "Inbound"} | set-netfirewallrule -Action Allow -Protocol TCP -LocalPort @($IdeatePortNo)
```

The firewall rule updates if I use the $tempPort variable, but returns the error when I use the $IdeatePortNo variable.

set-netfirewallrule : The port is invalid.  When Protocol is TCP or UDP, individual ports or ranges are allowed.  Also, the following port keywords are allowed on Firewall Rules: RPC,
RPCEPMap, Teredo, IPHTTPSIn, IPHTTPSOut, PlayToDiscovery.
At U:\Scripts\UpdateIdeateFirewallRule.ps1:15 char:94

- ... Inbound"} | set-netfirewallrule -Action Allow -Protocol TCP -LocalPor ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (MSFT_NetFirewal...ystemName = ""):root/standardcimv2/MSFT_NetFirewallRule) [Set-NetFirewallRule], CimException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070057,Set-NetFirewallRule

excerpt of log file

```
7:21:56 (lmgrd) -----------------------------------------------
 7:21:56 (lmgrd)   Please Note:
 7:21:56 (lmgrd) 
 7:21:56 (lmgrd)   This log is intended for debug purposes only.
 7:21:56 (lmgrd)   In order to capture accurate license
 7:21:56 (lmgrd)   usage data into an organized repository,
 7:21:56 (lmgrd)   please enable report logging. Use Flexera's
 7:21:56 (lmgrd)   software license administration  solution,
 7:21:56 (lmgrd)   FlexNet Manager, to  readily gain visibility
 7:21:56 (lmgrd)   into license usage data and to create
 7:21:56 (lmgrd)   insightful reports on critical information like
 7:21:56 (lmgrd)   license availability and usage. FlexNet Manager
 7:21:56 (lmgrd)   can be fully automated to run these reports on
 7:21:56 (lmgrd)   schedule and can be used to track license
 7:21:56 (lmgrd)   servers and usage across a heterogeneous
 7:21:56 (lmgrd)   network of servers including Windows NT, Linux
 7:21:56 (lmgrd)   and UNIX.
 7:21:56 (lmgrd) 
 7:21:56 (lmgrd) -----------------------------------------------
 7:21:56 (lmgrd) 
 7:21:56 (lmgrd) 
 7:21:56 (lmgrd) Server's System Date and Time: Mon Nov 16 2020 07:21:56 Pacific Standard Time
 7:21:56 (lmgrd) pid 6432
 7:21:56 (lmgrd) SLOG: Summary LOG statistics is enabled.
 7:21:56 (lmgrd) Detecting other license server manager (lmgrd) processes...
 7:21:59 (lmgrd) Done rereading
 7:21:59 (lmgrd) FlexNet Licensing (v11.16.2.0 build 242433 x64_n6) started on PANIC (IBM PC) (11/16/2020)
 7:21:59 (lmgrd) Copyright (c) 1988-2018 Flexera. All Rights Reserved.
 7:21:59 (lmgrd) World Wide Web:  http://www.flexerasoftware.com
 7:21:59 (lmgrd) License file(s): C:\Licenses\Ideate\Rushing_07-16_PANIC.lic
 7:21:59 (lmgrd) lmgrd tcp-port #####
 7:21:59 (lmgrd) (@lmgrd-SLOG@) ===============================================
 7:21:59 (lmgrd) (@lmgrd-SLOG@) === LMGRD ===
 7:21:59 (lmgrd) (@lmgrd-SLOG@) Start-Date: Mon Nov 16 2020 07:21:59 Pacific Standard Time
 7:21:59 (lmgrd) (@lmgrd-SLOG@) PID: 6432
 7:21:59 (lmgrd) (@lmgrd-SLOG@) LMGRD Version: v11.16.2.0 build 242433 x64_n6 ( build 242433 (ipv6))
 7:21:59 (lmgrd) (@lmgrd-SLOG@) 
 7:21:59 (lmgrd) (@lmgrd-SLOG@) === Network Info ===
 7:21:59 (lmgrd) (@lmgrd-SLOG@) Listening port: #####
 7:21:59 (lmgrd) (@lmgrd-SLOG@) 
 7:21:59 (lmgrd) (@lmgrd-SLOG@) === Startup Info ===
 7:21:59 (lmgrd) (@lmgrd-SLOG@) Is LS run as a service: Yes
 7:21:59 (lmgrd) (@lmgrd-SLOG@) Server Configuration: Single Server
 7:21:59 (lmgrd) (@lmgrd-SLOG@) Command-line options used at LS startup: -c C:\Licenses\Ideate\Rushing_07-16_#####.lic -l C:\Autodesk\Network License Manager\ideate.log -z -s 
 7:21:59 (lmgrd) (@lmgrd-SLOG@) License file(s) used:  C:\Licenses\Ideate\Rushing_07-16_#####.lic
 7:21:59 (lmgrd) (@lmgrd-SLOG@) ===============================================
 7:21:59 (lmgrd) SLOG: FNPLS-INTERNAL-VL1-4096
 7:21:59 (lmgrd) Starting vendor daemons ... 
 7:21:59 (lmgrd) Started ideate (pid 7552)
 7:21:59 (ideate) FLEXnet Licensing version v11.9.1.0 build 89952 x64_n6
 7:21:59 (ideate) lmgrd version 11.16, ideate version 11.9

 7:21:59 (ideate) Server started on ##### for:  
 7:21:59 (ideate) IBL (consisting of:       BIMLink_2012    
 7:21:59 (ideate) BIMLink_2013  BIMLink_2014    BIMLink_2015    
 7:21:59 (ideate) BIMLink_2016  BIMLink_2017    BIMLink_2018    
 7:21:59 (ideate) BIMLink_2019  BIMLink_2020    BIMLink_2021    
 7:21:59 (ideate) BIMLink_2022) 
 7:21:59 (ideate) IEX (consisting of:       Explorer_2012   
 7:21:59 (ideate) Explorer_2013 Explorer_2014   Explorer_2015   
 7:21:59 (ideate) Explorer_2016 Explorer_2017   Explorer_2018   
 7:21:59 (ideate) Explorer_2019 Explorer_2020   Explorer_2021   
 7:21:59 (ideate) Explorer_2022)    
 7:21:59 (ideate) ISB (consisting of:       Sticky_2014 
 7:21:59 (ideate) Sticky_2015   Sticky_2016 Sticky_2017 
 7:21:59 (ideate) Sticky_2018   Sticky_2019 Sticky_2020 
 7:21:59 (ideate) Sticky_2021   Sticky_2022)    
 7:21:59 (ideate) Apps (consisting of:      IdeateApps_2015 
 7:21:59 (ideate) IdeateApps_2016 IdeateApps_2017 IdeateApps_2018 
 7:21:59 (ideate) IdeateApps_2019 IdeateApps_2020 IdeateApps_2021 
 7:21:59 (ideate) IdeateApps_2022) 
 7:21:59 (ideate) STL (consisting of:       StyleManager_2016 
 7:21:59 (ideate) StyleManager_2017 StyleManager_2018 StyleManager_2019 
 7:21:59 (ideate) StyleManager_2020 StyleManager_2021 StyleManager_2022) 
 7:21:59 (ideate) EXTERNAL FILTERS are OFF
 7:21:59 (lmgrd) ideate using TCP-port 65443
 8:01:40 (ideate) TCP_NODELAY NOT enabled
```

Here is my error when I try "$($matches.1)" [image]

Comment: You should show example of what the log file looks like and you'll surely get better recommendations on solving your issue. There is almost certainly an easier approach than replacing plus substring plus concatenation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. here is an excerpt of the log file:

Answer (score 2):

Since the only value you're after is a port number, the code can be simplified to

```
$IdeateLog = "C:\Autodesk\Network License Manager\ideate.log"

$content = Get-Content $IdeateLog

if($content -match 'ideate using TCP-port (\d{1,5})')
{
    get-netfirewallrule -DisplayName "*LMtools - Ideate*" | where {$_.Direction -eq "Inbound"} |
        set-netfirewallrule -Action Allow -Protocol TCP -LocalPort "$($matches.1)"
}
```

The pattern will only match the line with `ideate using TCP-port` and the pattern `\d{1,5}` will match and number that is 1 to 5 digits long.

**Edit**

Looking at the help for `Set-NetFirewallrule` it shows local port to be a string array. That's likely why the number by itself isn't working where your literal string does. I've edited the answer to force the number to be a string.

Comment: Thank you, Doug!

Comment: You’re welcome! If you found the answer helpful, please consider upvoting it. If it solved your issue, consider marking it as the accepted answer. You can always change it later if a better answer is provided.

Comment: Hi Doug, the $matches.1 variable is not being updated in the firewall rule. If I replace it with a number 9999 or a static variable $tempPort = 8888, both will update.

Comment: What if you change it to  “$($matches.1)”

Comment: It still didn't work with $($matches.1). Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You forgot the quotes, specifically double quotes

Comment: I actually did try that first. I receive the error:  set-netfirewallrule : The port is invalid.  When Protocol is TCP or UDP, individual ports or ranges are allowed.  Also, the following port keywords are allowed on Firewall Rules: RPC, 
RPCEPMap, Teredo, IPHTTPSIn, IPHTTPSOut, PlayToDiscovery.
At C:\Users\markuse\Documents\UpdateIdeateFirewallRule.ps1:12 char:9
+         set-netfirewallrule -Action Allow -Protocol TCP -LocalPort "$ ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Yeah you must have something else going on, the original suggestion worked fine.
https://imgur.com/Iz14OR7